# Bash Script Array Separated by pipe and bracket

Tags: linux, text-processing

I need to create a bash script that would transform the text file content separated by | and ] ...

Text File Content for example:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|P1]P2]P3|D1]D2]D3||Col4 
Col3|ColA|ColA|PA]PB]|DA]DB]|ColD||
```

The desired output would be:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 P1 D1 0 Col4
Col1 Col2 Col3 P2 D2 0 Col4
Col1 Col2 Col3 P3 D3 0 Col4
Col3 ColA ColA PA DA ColD 0
Col3 ColA ColA PB DB ColD 0
Col3 ColA ColA 0 0 ColD 0
```

EDITED: blank column and blank data after ] would all be replaced by 0

Thank you.

Comment: What does this have to do with an array (as mentioned in the title)?

Comment: Can the first 2 columns also contain `]` characters?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: If you have a different question with different requirements, don't edit your question with the new requirements, post a separate question, possibly referencing this one for context if you like. Also please try and specify the exact requirements. An example is not enough.

Comment: Apologized as I am new to this. The only difference from the previous one was the replacing empty column and field to '0' or NULL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it via sample script (mine is not optimal but will work)

```
awk -F'[]|]' '{
   print $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$10
   print $1,$2,$3,$5,$8,$10
   print $1,$2,$3,$6,$9,$10 }' input_filename
```

Or

```
awk -F'[]|]' '{
   for (i = 4; i <= 6; i++)
     print $1,$2,$3,$i,$(i+3),$10}' input_filename
```

You can change the *output field separator* (space by default) by adding `-v OFS=','`.

And thanks to @steeldriver one more flexible way (with internal separation of field) to do the job:

```
awk -F'|' '{
  split($3,a,/]/); n = split($4,b,/]/); 
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1,$2,a[1],a[i+1],b[i],$5}' input_filename
```

As per edited question if you want to replace empty field with `0` (zero) you can do it with script like:

```
awk -F'[]|]' '{ 
   for (i = 1; i <= 11; i++) if ($i == "") $i=0}
   {
   print $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$10,$11
   print $1,$2,$3,$5,$8,$10,$11
   print $1,$2,$3,$6,$9,$10,$11 }' input_filename
```

From your comment the script should look like:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="\t" '{
 n = split($4,D,"]"); split($5,E,"]");
 for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     if (D[i] == "") D[i]=0;
     if (E[i] == "") E[i]=0;}
     print $1,$2,$3,D[i],E[i],$6,$7 }' input_file
```

Comment: @RichmondMagpayo, if the answer work for you feel free to upvote and/or accept it :)

Comment: Hi Romeo yep it worked like magic, imma have to try and play with the other suggestion too, but already tested this working. Now how to accept or upvote this. Im new here :) sorry --- Got it :)

Comment: Why do you say it's not optimal?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, first thank you about the idea with `for` :) And "maybe" there is way to do it with kind of logic (do not explicit select values)

Comment: You could make it less hard-coded by using only `|` as the FS and then doing further splits on `]` e.g. `awk -F'|' '{split($3,a,/]/); n = split($4,b,/]/); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1,$2,a[1],a[i+1],b[i],$5}'` however this still assumes a particular relationship between the number of subfields in `$3` and `$4`

Comment: Hey Romeo, the first 2, works like magic, but the last one doesnt output as desired hehe

Comment: @RichmondMagpayo, can you add description of problem, for me all three produce the same output. And please reconsider accepted answer a currently accepted by you answer is deleted.

Comment: Well, the one you gave is already working. I was thinking it can be possible to have a dynamic code that would format as stated above. The other 2 codes, did not separate the payments and date ( or P1 and D1). Although we still do not have the actual format of the file that we will be reformating soon before we upload it to database, they already gave us the sample format which was mentioned on original post.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I meant because the data is not static, so everyday, it could have 2 payments (P) and (D) or more... So how could I put it in a way that it would be dynamic to counter how many data inside | and explode it on another row.

Comment: @RichmondMagpayo, You should provide examples of variations of input data in the question

Comment: @RomeoNinov, Hi... The sample input data is somewhat the same, but my concern is for example on a daily basis there will be more payments and dates, so I need to have a code that would format them as stated in the sample. Real data would have like 500 rows T_T

Comment: @RichmondMagpayo, you should check the scripts with real data by hand and see if they do what you want. You can post anonymized example from real data so we can be sure about the things.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, Ok thank you. I will get back here whenever we have the actual data to play with. Thank you again for all your time.

Comment: @RomeoNinov ...Hi again, so far already using the code and working fine, could you help me on something again.... I would like to replace blank column with '0' on the same input data.... example: ACT1|P1]P2]]|D1|D2]]| |C ...

Output should be: ACT1 P1 D1 0 C
ACT1 P2 D2 0 C
ACT1 0 0 0 C

Comment: @RichmondMagpayo, I would recommend you to create new question with explanations and link to this question also. The philosophy of this site is one question and answers.

Comment: But it is still part of the actual problem, just that didnt expect that we needed to replace blank columns with 0 ...please.

Comment: @RichmondMagpayo please edit the question and add criteria how to recognize empty column (it's not clear for me)

Comment: @RomeoNinov edited now, as well as the input file sample. Sorry and Thank you.

Comment: @RichmondMagpayo, please check my edited answer

Comment: @RichmondMagpayo, IMHO there is discrepancy in your input data, please check again

Comment: @RomeoNinov corrected the input, thank you for noticing.

Currently I have, 

awk -F'|' -v OFS="\t" '{
        n = split($4,D,"]");
            split($5,E,"]");

                for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) if ($i == "") $i=0}
        {

        print $1,$2,$3,D[i],E[i],$6,$7
}' input_file

But can't seem to make it work

Comment: @RichmondMagpayo, see edited question

Comment: @RichmondMagpayo, then input file is again problematic, please check again

Comment: Thank you very much @RomeoNinov ...did few tweaks its working now. I suppose

Answer (score 4):

Another `awk` take at the problem:

```
awk -F'|' '
  {
    n = split($4, f4, "]")
        split($3, f3, "]")
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      $3 = f3[1] OFS f3[1+i]
      $4 = f4[i]
      print
    }
  }'
```

Comment: Can make it something dynamic, like if there is a bracket ] inside a pipe | then it will explode just like on the sample, as it could have it on 2nd col or other column too. Thank you again for all help. Very much appreciated and all are working.

Comment: The output isnt the desired...

COL1 COL2 COL3  PAYMENT1 DATE1]DATE2]DATE3 COL4
COL1 COL2 COL3  PAYMENT2 DATE1]DATE2]DATE3 COL4
COL1 COL2 COL3  PAYMENT3 DATE1]DATE2]DATE3 COL4
COL11 COL21 COL31  PAYMENT11 DATE11]DATE21]DATE31 COL41
COL11 COL21 COL31  PAYMENT21 DATE11]DATE21]DATE31 COL41
COL11 COL21 COL31  PAYMENT31 DATE11]DATE21]DATE31 COL41